# Change sql server instance name to AG listener for sharepoint

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, alwayson

Recently our sharepoint admin deployed new farm using Sql Server instance name without using alias.

Now i want to change the sql instance name to SQL Listener in sharepoint farm for high availability.

Is it possible? 
How to go about it?
What could be the implications as it is a production server?

I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I dont believe it will have any adverse affect on sharepoint, in the sharepoint settings, you just enter the listener name instead of the actual server name. When failover occurs, sharepoint shouldnt be any the wiser as it is now abstracted from the physical sql server.

make sure youre aware of the licensing requirements with Always On and also if your in synchronous or async commit mode. synchronous can sometimes be a small performance hit which is remedied by async mode at the expense of potential data loss. As sharepoint is a "black box", i.e. you dont really know what its writing to the database at any given time, there is risk that if any critical system data is lost the instance will be damaged.

Comment: Can i add an alias now with listener name and use it?

Comment: yes. im assuming sharepoint is up and running against a standalone instance of sql server. you should be able to take sharepoint offline, make the sharepoint databases highly available in a HA cluster with a listener, then change the database server name in sharepoint settings to the listener.